# Spring data CrudRepository (hibernate) findone return null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

For some reason I cannot find existing entity by Id

The entity has the following view:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "includeRemunerationAndCredential",attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode("remunerations"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("credentials")
})
@JsonSerialize
public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
@NotNull
private String firstName;

@Column(name= "second_name",  nullable = false, length = 50)
@NotNull
private String secondName;

@Column(name = "father_name", length = 50)
private String fatherName;

@Column(name = "phone_number", length = 20)
private String phoneNumber;

@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
private LocalDateTime dateOfBirth;

@Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 50)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role role;

@Column(name = "date_of_creation", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private LocalDateTime dateOfCreation;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "carwash")
private CarWash carWash;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
private List<Remuneration> remunerations;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
private Set<Credential> credentials;

@Column(name = "enable", nullable = false)
private Boolean enable;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner", nullable = false)
private Owner owner;

// getters and setters

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Person person = (Person) o;

    return id != null ? id.equals(person.id) : person.id == null;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", secondName='" + secondName + '\'' +
            ", fatherName='" + fatherName + '\'' +
            ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
            ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth +
            ", role=" + role +
            ", dateOfCreation=" + dateOfCreation +
            ", carWash=" + (carWash == null ? carWash : carWash.getId()) +
            ", remunerations=" + (remunerations == null ? remunerations : remunerations.size()) +
            ", enable=" + enable +
            ", owner=" + (owner == null ? "N/A" : owner.getName()) +
            '}';
}
```

my DAO the the following view:

```
public interface PersonDAO extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

and my service is presented by this class

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class MyUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
PersonDAO personDAO;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    //final Iterable<Person> all = personDAO.findAll();
    final Person one = personDAO.findOne(15L);

    return null;
}
```

So if in the service `personDAO.findAll()` fill be commented then `personDAO.findOne(15L)` returns null but if `findAll()` will be uncommitted the `findOne(15L)` will be found. Hot to fix this that `findOne` works without `findAll()` ?

Comment: why are you returning null?

Comment: Clearly, the id persisted is NOT 15. Prove it - show your database.

Comment: I return null just to decrease method size. In any case it does not have any reaction on spring data

Comment: How does the data get into the database? Is it already there? Or does it get inserted by some other code? If the later show us that code.

Comment: It sounds like the findAll might trigger a flush.

Answer (score 0):

I have just run exactly in the same issue some days ago, then i have found out that the reason why this was happening was that the entity which i was retrieving had a foreign reference to another entity which thereafter had as well another foreign reference to a third entity and the latter of these [references] was configured as not nullable, but the problem was that when checking in the database the looked item had effectively a null value in the foreign key; so when the persistence framework was translating the service into a query, it was making an inner join rather than an outer join which removed the entity from the results since the join between the second and third entity was failing due to the null values.

Removing the above described not nullable clause in the field of the second entity fixed the issue [in the service that was retrieving the first entity]

Please check if your entities are not mapped in similar way: i can see for instance that the entity Person has a foreign reference to an entity Owner which is not nullable; maybe owner is null and that is the problem? If it is not null, please do **check all of the other foreign references and thereafter all of the chains of inner references to additional other third entities to ensure that you are not enforcing not null in one of these fields where the relative column is instead effectively nullable.**